# Convert array to string react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I want to convert the following array (**userNameApp**) into string so I can insert the following array into the database as a string

```
        var userInfo = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('current-session'));
        const userNameApp = useState(userInfo['fname'] + " " + userInfo['lname']);
        console.log(userNameApp);
```

In the console log, the result is **First Name + Last Name**.
When inserting in the database, I will post it like this

```
 Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/insertActiveUser", {userNameApp: userNameApp}))
```

Inside the database schema/model, the type of Value is string.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User Details = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    Username: String,
  },
  {
    collection: "AppointmentDetails",
  }
);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the question...

Comment: I want to convert **userNameApp** into a string

Comment: You should read about [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) Your wish of converting `userNameApp` into a string doesn't make any sense, because the second element of `userNameApp`is a `function`

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `userNameApp` should be fixed to:

```
const [userNameApp, setUserNameApp] = useState(userInfo['fname'] + " " + userInfo['lname']);
```

**Explanation**

What returns from `useState` is an array of two values: the first value is the value we want to be able to set and use, and the second value is the `set` function.

If we'll want to re-set the variable `userNameApp` the correct way of doing it will be: `setUserNameApp(newValue)`.

The value that we pass to `useState` will be the initial value.

Comment: you probably mean `useState` and not `setState` ...

Answer (score 0):

What I did is

```
 var userInfo = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('current-session'));
 var getUserName = JSON.stringify(userInfo['fname'] + " " + userInfo['lname'])
 const userNameApp = JSON.parse(getUserName)
```